# How can I create comma separated array of arrays

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to create WP_Query that looks like this:

```
array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 10114,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 54,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 77,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ), 
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 31,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ) 
),
```

I need to create this array dynamically, so, my question is how can I create array like this one?

```
array(array(),array(),array())
```

I am always getting indexed array and not able to get it like this above.

Tried this:

```
    $courseQuery = array();
if (isset($courses) && !empty($courses)) {    
    $n = 0;
    foreach ($courses as $course) {
        $courseID = $course[$n];
        $itemArray = array();
        $itemArray['key'] = 'course';
        $itemArray['value'] = $courseID;
        $itemArray['compare'] = 'LIKE';
        array_push($courseQuery, $itemArray);
        $n++;
    }
    print_r ($courseQuery);
}
```

But I get indexed array and need comma separated arrays in array.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried menu things.. this for example

Comment: $courseQuery = array();
    if (isset($courses) && !empty($courses)) {    
        $n = 0;
        foreach ($courses as $course) {
            $courseID = $course[$n];
            $itemArray = array();
            $itemArray['key'] = 'course';
            $itemArray['value'] = $courseID;
            $itemArray['compare'] = 'LIKE';
            array_push($courseQuery, $itemArray);
            $n++;
        }
        print_r ($courseQuery);
//        $courseQuery = array_values($courseQuery);


    }

Comment: but it turns indexed array. tried to make a string but it didn't work. Searched everywhere but didn't found any solution.

Comment: @IlyaBursov Why did you sent me this link? I know where I can find php manual but still don't know how to figure this.

Comment: @radoya first example in this link is how you can define custom keys to get non-indexed array...

Comment: @IlyaBursov I know that.. I don't know how can I create array like this one: array(array(),array(),array()) - this is my question.

Comment: @radoya try `var_dump` instead of `print_r`

Comment: @IlyaBursov var_dump will not return array that I need. This is what I need: array(array(),array(),array()) thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: @radoya you're mixing array internal structure with string representation, you already constructing array you need, it is just printed differently

Comment: @radoya try this code and you will see `$a = array(array(), array(), array());print_r($a);var_dump($a);var_export($a);`

Comment: @IlyaBursov Thanks again for your help.. I tried to pass this array to query again but it want work. I printed out query and it still have indexed array in it. If it's the same why it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the line:

```
'relation' => 'OR',
```

This is a an indexed pair, by including it in your array, PHP will always create an indexed array.
Try this:

```
array(
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 10114,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 54,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 77,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ), 
    array(
        'key' => 'course',
        'value' => 31,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ) 
),
```

Comment: Does I need to use something else than array_push? this line is irelevant.. 'relation' => 'OR', it stayed from something I tried later.

Comment: If it is irrelevant, get rid of it. this should work the way you asked.

Comment: you just paste me somethin that I have to create dynamically. How can I create array like this one by looping, for example, I have array like array(1, 5, 6, 12, 55) and I need to loop through this and get something you paste me abowe?